# OSError: cannot identify image file in CNN

Tags: python, keras

I'm using keras librairy, and when I try to run a train of model with `classifier.fit_generator(training_set,samples_per_epoch = 50, nb_epoch = 5,validation_data = test_set, nb_val_samples = 20)`

i get this error `OSError: cannot identify image file 'dataset/training_set\\cow\\OIP-FEq-NuYf4tBwOAHanAfxPQHaFP.jpeg'`.

if any one here can help me 
my code is the following:

````
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                   shear_range = 0.2,
                                   zoom_range = 0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip = True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/training_set',
                                                 target_size = (64, 64),
                                                 batch_size = 32,
                                                 class_mode = 'binary')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset\test_set',
                                            target_size = (64, 64),
                                            batch_size = 32,
                                            class_mode = 'binary')

classifier.fit_generator(training_set,
                         samples_per_epoch = 50,
                         nb_epoch = 5,
                         validation_data = test_set,
                         nb_val_samples = 20) ```
````

Comment: Please share the entire error message.

Comment: Does your filename have forward slashes in it? If you are using Linux please change the file name to "dataset/training_set/cow/OIP-FEq-NuYf4tBwOAHanAfxPQHaFP.jpeg"

Comment: @AMC Traceback (most recent call last): 
 File "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 786, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)  
  File "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\utils.py", line 110, in load_img
    img = pil_image.open(path)
File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2818, in open
    raise IOError("cannot identify image file %r" % (filename if filename else fp))
OSError: cannot identify image file 'dataset\\training_set\\Bear\\Bear20.jpg'

Comment: @jhso I using windows and I changed the slaches but error sill the same

Comment: Ok then, make sure you are using backwards slashes then. This might sound silly, but since you're using a relative path, is the 'dataset' folder in the exact location you are running the code from?

Comment: @jhso thank u for your response, yeah the 'dataset' and the code file in the same folder . the problem is the error is random in each running give another location of error. however error is the same but location differs.